# How can i parse this json file in android studio?

Tags: android, json

how can i parse this json file because the text do not have any particular indexing names

```
 {
      "titles": [
        " Thoughts On The Works Of Providence",
        "\"All Is Vanity, Saith the Preacher\"",
        "\"And the sins of the fathers shall be\"",
        "\"Arcturus\" is his other name",
        "\"By the Waters of Babylon.\"",
        "\"De Gustibus--\"",
        "\"Faith\" is a fine invention",
        "\"Faithful to the end\" Amended",
        "\"Heaven\" -- is what I cannot reach!",
        "\"Heaven\" has different Signs -- to me --",
        "\"Heavenly Father\" -- take to thee",
        "\"Home\"",
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("titles");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i ++){
        String title = array.getString(i);

        //Do something with the string
    }
```

You treat the `JsonArray` like a string array.
However in the array you provided the JSON is invalid because of the comma on the last element of the array, you need to remove this comma to have valid JSON.

Comment: You can also use the Gson library to parse into an object.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple JSON. Do it like this.

```
String json = "{\"titles\":[\" Thoughts On The Works Of Providence\",\"\\\"All Is Vanity, Saith the Preacher\\\"\",\"\\\"And the sins of the fathers shall be\\\"\",\"\\\"Arcturus\\\" is his other name\",\"\\\"By the Waters of Babylon.\\\"\",\"\\\"De Gustibus--\\\"\",\"\\\"Faith\\\" is a fine invention\",\"\\\"Faithful to the end\\\" Amended\",\"\\\"Heaven\\\" -- is what I cannot reach!\",\"\\\"Heaven\\\" has different Signs -- to me --\",\"\\\"Heavenly Father\\\" -- take to thee\",\"\\\"Home\\\"\"]}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

And for accessing your items:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("titles");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.size(); i++){
    Log.d(TAG, jsonArray.getString(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this to an instanse of this class :

```
public class Instance{
   public String[] titles;
}
```

but you need to remove the last comma after home. If there is no another item after the comma, it means it is not a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourString);
JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("titles");
for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    string content = jsonArray.getString(i);

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Try{
   JSONArray itemArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("titles")
   for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
        String value=itemArray.getString(i);
        Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
   }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```